# Bootstrap Input Password Show Hide with bootstrap-float-label css

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, input

I am using Bootstrap **bootstrap-float-label** with all my forms inputs.
Ref => https://github.com/tonystar/bootstrap-float-label/blob/master/bootstrap-float-label.css
Note => I have made changes as per my requirements and I have added my modified bootstrap-float-label.css in Code Snipet.

**Case :** for Password input field

**Example-1** Without bootstrap-float-label, Password show/hide is working perfect.

**Example-2** With bootstrap-float-label, Password show/hide is not working.

*Example-2 problem =>* In old password field, after insert password, when I click **Show**, `<span class="has-float-label"` gets `type="password"` because I am using 2 times `prev().prev()`.
I can't figure out how to get into `<span class="has-float-label"` and find `<input type="password"` and toggle value to text/password.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.pass_show').append('<span class="ptxt">Show</span>');
});
$(document).on('click','.pass_show .ptxt', function(){ 
 $(this).text($(this).text() == "Show" ? "Hide" : "Show");
 $(this).prev().prev().attr('type', function(index, attr){return attr == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'; });
});
```

```css
/*bootstrap-float-label.css*/
.has-float-label{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
}
.has-float-label label,.has-float-label>span{
 position:absolute;
 cursor:text;
 font-size:75%;
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s;
 transition:all .2s;
 top:-.5em;
 left:.75rem;
 z-index:3;
 line-height:1;
 padding:0 3px;
 background:#fff;
 font-weight:normal;
}
.has-float-label>span{/*For select2-bootstrap dropdown set top,left margin 0*/
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
.has-float-label label::after,.has-float-label>span::after{
 content:" ";
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 background:#fff;
 height:2px;
 top:50%;
 left:-.2em;
 right:-.2em;
 z-index:-1;
}
.has-float-label .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s;
 transition:all .2s;
}
.has-float-label .form-control::-moz-placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 transition:all .2s;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 transition:all .2s;
}
.has-float-label .form-control::placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s;
 transition:all .2s;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder{
 opacity:0;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-moz-placeholder{
 opacity:0;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus):-ms-input-placeholder{
 opacity:0;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::placeholder{
 opacity:0;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)+*{
 font-size:100%;
 color: #6c757d;
 opacity: 1;
 top:.3em;
}
.input-group .has-float-label{
 -webkit-box-flex:1;
 -webkit-flex-grow:1;
 -ms-flex-positive:1;
 flex-grow:1;
 margin-bottom:0;
 display:-webkit-box;
 display:-webkit-flex;
 display:-ms-flexbox;
 display:flex;
 -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction:normal;
 -webkit-flex-direction:column;
 -ms-flex-direction:column;
 flex-direction:column;
 -webkit-box-pack:center;
 -webkit-justify-content:center;
 -ms-flex-pack:center;
 justify-content:center;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus) + * {
 margin-top: 6px;
}

/*pass_show*/
.pass_show {
 position: relative
}
.pass_show .ptxt {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right: 10px;
 z-index: 1;
 color: #f36c01;
 margin-top: -10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: .3s ease all;
}
.pass_show .ptxt:hover {
 color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group"><b>EXAMPLE-1 : Without bootstrap-float-label.css</b></div>
      <div class="form-group pass_show">
        <label for="opass">Old Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" name="opass" class="form-control" id="opass" placeholder="Old Password" required="required" autocomplete="off">
        <span id="error_opass" class="error"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"><b>EXAMPLE-2 : With bootstrap-float-label.css</b></div>
      <div class="form-group pass_show">
        <span class="has-float-label">
        <input type="password" name="txtoldpass" class="form-control" id="txtoldpass" placeholder="Old Password" required="required" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="txtoldpass">Old Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
        </span>
        <span id="error_oldpass" class="error"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group pass_show">
        <span class="has-float-label">
        <input type="password" name="txtnewpass" class="form-control" id="txtnewpass" placeholder="New Password" required="required" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="txtnewpass">New Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
        </span>
        <span class="instruction">Password must have a minimum of 8 characters and Include: at least 1 number, at least 1 uppercase letter, at least 1 lowercase letter, at least 1 special character.</span><br>
        <span id="error_newpass" class="error"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for Password Show/Hide when using Bootstrap **bootstrap-float-label**

**Solution =>** apply class `pass_show` to `<span class="has-float-label` and remove from `<div class="form-group">`

**Before =>**

```
<div class="form-group pass_show">
    <span class="has-float-label">
```

**Change =>**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span class="has-float-label pass_show">
```

Also I changed the `.ptxt` css.

```
.ptxt {
    color:#3366cc;
    float: right !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
    left: auto !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    top: 30% !important;
    right: 10px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.pass_show').append('<span class="ptxt">Show</span>');
});
$(document).on('click','.pass_show .ptxt', function(){ 
 $(this).text($(this).text() == "Show" ? "Hide" : "Show");
 $(this).prev().prev().attr('type', function(index, attr){return attr == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'; });
});
```

```css
/*bootstrap-float-label.css*/
.has-float-label{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
}
.has-float-label label,.has-float-label>span{
 position:absolute;
 cursor:text;
 font-size:75%;
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s;
 transition:all .2s;
 top:-.5em;
 left:.75rem;
 z-index:3;
 line-height:1;
 padding:0 3px;
 background:#fff;
 font-weight:normal;
}
.has-float-label>span{/*For select2-bootstrap dropdown set top,left margin 0*/
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
.has-float-label label::after,.has-float-label>span::after{
 content:" ";
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 background:#fff;
 height:2px;
 top:50%;
 left:-.2em;
 right:-.2em;
 z-index:-1;
}
.has-float-label .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s;
 transition:all .2s;
}
.has-float-label .form-control::-moz-placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 transition:all .2s;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 transition:all .2s;
}
.has-float-label .form-control::placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s;
 transition:all .2s;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder{
 opacity:0;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-moz-placeholder{
 opacity:0;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus):-ms-input-placeholder{
 opacity:0;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::placeholder{
 opacity:0;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)+*{
 font-size:100%;
 color: #6c757d;
 opacity: 1;
 top:.3em;
}
.input-group .has-float-label{
 -webkit-box-flex:1;
 -webkit-flex-grow:1;
 -ms-flex-positive:1;
 flex-grow:1;
 margin-bottom:0;
 display:-webkit-box;
 display:-webkit-flex;
 display:-ms-flexbox;
 display:flex;
 -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction:normal;
 -webkit-flex-direction:column;
 -ms-flex-direction:column;
 flex-direction:column;
 -webkit-box-pack:center;
 -webkit-justify-content:center;
 -ms-flex-pack:center;
 justify-content:center;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus) + * {
 margin-top: 6px;
}

/*pass_show*/
.ptxt {
 color:#3366cc;
 float: right !important;
 font-size: 15px !important;
 left: auto !important;
 background: transparent !important;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer !important;
 top: 30% !important;
 right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group"><b>EXAMPLE-2 : With bootstrap-float-label.css</b></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="has-float-label pass_show">
        <input type="password" name="txtoldpass" class="form-control" id="txtoldpass" placeholder="Old Password" required="required" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="txtoldpass">Old Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
        </span>
        <span id="error_oldpass" class="error"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="has-float-label pass_show">
        <input type="password" name="txtnewpass" class="form-control" id="txtnewpass" placeholder="New Password" required="required" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="txtnewpass">New Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
        </span>
        <span class="instruction">Password must have a minimum of 8 characters and Include: at least 1 number, at least 1 uppercase letter, at least 1 lowercase letter, at least 1 special character.</span><br>
        <span id="error_newpass" class="error"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are putting `type` attribute on the `<div class="has-float-label">`
So you just need to change your jquery code a little bit and pass id or class of input element.

So turn this:

```
$(this).prev().prev().attr('type', function(index, attr){return attr == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'; });
```

Into this:

```
$(this).prev().children().attr('type', function(index, attr){return attr == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'; });
```

If this doesn't solve the problem then kindly post a comment. Thanks.

Comment: I changed it to `prev().children()` but it doesn't work